# i could not able to connect to my VM instance

Tags: virtual-machine, rdp

I have a VM instance running for the past two weeks on Google Cloud now. I was not able to connect to it from my Windows desktop using RD Connection. I tried deleting and creating new instances also, but no use.

I have created my new instance from my previous project image.

Comment: you need to provide more details in order to get the answer that can help you. You can explore this link in order to learn how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask